# How do I pass build variables as properties to MSBuild using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm in the process of converting Jenkins Freestyle jobs to Declarative Pipeline, and I've run into a problem. I've reached the part of the old job definition for "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild", and I've replicated the command in my pipeline file. It calls MSBuild as expected, but the original job has a checkbox next to "Pass Build Variables as Properties". I can't seem to find any documentation on how to replicate this in a Jenkinsfile, and I suspect it may be at least partly why the build is failing.

As per a previous question I found on stackoverflow, this is my msbuild step.

```
script {
  def msbuild = tool name: 'default', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'
  bat "${msbuild} code/SolutionFile.sln /p:Configuration=\"MyApp - Release\" /p:Platform=TargetPlatform /m /t:Rebuild"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If within your code:

```
script {
   def slnpath = "repo\\solution.sln"
   def congifA = "Debug"
   bat "MSBuild ${slnpath} /p:Configuration=${congifA}"
}
```

if passing from another job

```
parameters {
        text(name: 'congifA', defaultValue: "Debug", description: 'Debug or Release')
    }
```